# Python Requests: Data is scraped only sometimes

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using Python Requests library to scrape data from Yahoo Finance.
It sometimes works and I get the data that I want.

However most of the time, the data returned is `null`.
Have you ever encountered a similar issue? If yes, what did you do to fix it?

Here is my code:

```py
    def my_parse_json_outstanding_shares(url):

    headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) \
        AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.5 Safari/605.1.15'}

    html = requests.get(url=url, headers = headers).text

    json_str = html.split('root.App.main =')[1].split(
        '(this)')[0].split(';\n}')[0].strip()

    try:
        data = json.loads(json_str)[
            'context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteTimeSeriesStore']
    except:
        return '{}'
    else:
        # return data
        new_data = json.dumps(data).replace('{}', 'null')
        new_data = re.sub(r'\{[\'|\"]raw[\'|\"]:(.*?),(.*?)\}', r'\1', new_data)

        json_info = json.loads(new_data)

        return json_info
```

When it is not working, the `data` I get is:

```json
"QuoteTimeSeriesStore": {
  "timeSeries": null,
  "meta": {
      "timeUnit": "annual"
      },
   "loading": false,
   "errorList": [
      "QUOTE_TIMESERIES_LOAD"
      ]
   },
```

When it is working, `timeSeries` is not equal to null.

Comment: I suspect, the reason you are getting nulls is that the request is opening a url which builds it's display using a java script.  A better approach might be to utilize the [yfinance library](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/)  which has been designed to pull financial data from Yahoo.

Comment: Not familiar with Yahoo finance but I can see that your "bad" `data` has `"errorList": ["QUOTE_TIMESERIES_LOAD"]`. What is `errorList` for correct `data`? If it empty, looks like because of some reasons some error appears at Yahoo's side

Comment: first you should check what you really get in HTML. Maybe there is warning for bots/spamers and it asks for ReCaptcha. OR maybe there is some useful explanation what is the problem.

Comment: @rzlvmp Hello, I checked the errorList for the correct data, and here is the result I got:  "errorList": []. It is empty. How would you analyze it? For correct data, the errorList is empty. For wrong data, it is equal to QUOTE_TIMESERIES_LOAD.

Comment: @furas Hello, I am not familiar with bots/spamers indicators. From your experience, which marks/tags/words would tell me there is a warming for bots/spamers in the HTML ?

Comment: @itprorh66 Hello and thanks for your advice. I am currently using the yahoo_fin library. There is currently no function which allows to retrieve the shares outstanding per year, so I built my own function (def my_parse_json_outstanding_shares(url)) based on the yahoo_fun existing functions... and unfortunately, I get the data I want only sometimes. Because of that, I tend to think the same as you: When I send a request to scrap the HTML, the javascript has not yet finished building its HTML code and I only get a part of it. Therefore, would you know a way to overcome such issue ?

Comment: there is no speical marks/tags/works to check it - you shouls display full HTML (`response.text`) to see what is in HTML.

Comment: if page uses JavaScript to add elements then you can't get elements using `requests` because it can't run JavaScript. It would need ie. [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: frankly. it would be simpler if you would create minimal working code with URL which you use - this way we could simply copy and run code to check if we have the same problem. Maybe you don't get results because page detected script and it send something different - and then it may need to use proxy servers to run requests with different IP.